# Why doesn't the explicit specifier on a constructor prevent upcasts?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm probably misunderstanding the `explicit` specifier. But why does the following code compile?

```
struct A {
};

struct B : A {
};

struct C {
  A* a_;
  explicit C(A* a) : a_(a) { }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  C c(&b);
}
```

The base class `C` constructor is called with a `B*` which is implicitly upcast to an `A*`. I thought the `explicit` specifier was intended to prevent implicit conversion of arguments?

I'm asking because I understand it is good practice to add the `explicit` specifier to single argument constructors and I want to check my compiler is not letting me do something I shouldn't be doing.

Comment: You could use `struct C { C(A*); C(B*) = delete; };` or even `struct C { C(A*); template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<A, T>{} >::type> C(T*) = delete; };`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`explicit` prevents the constructor *itself* from being used as an implicit conversion for some other expression. It doesn't prevent you from employing implicit conversions when invoking it.

There's no way to prevent the compiler from performing a particular conversion from one primitive type to another (and pointers are primitive types).

Answer (score 2):

As Sneftel points out, `explicit` only prevents the constructor itself being used implicitly. To provide an example:

```
void testFunc(C c) {
    //do stuff
}

int main {
    A a;
    testFunc(&a);
}
```

will not work with the `explicit` keyword. If you remove it, however, the compiler will implicitly call the constructor for `C` that takes `&a` as an argument and run the code.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the example. I see `C c = &a` will not work either.